# sorting the multiple strings in a attribute in R Programming

Tags: r

I am novice to R. Please suggest me.I have a data like this:

```
data <- c("Room Service|Internet Access|Free Internet", 
  "Room Service|Free Internet", 
  "Swimming Pool|Room Service|Free Internet",
  "Room Service|Swimming Pool|Restaurant|Free Internet", 
  "Room Service")
```

I need to sort each record in alphabetical order

(Desired Output)

```
Free Internet,Internet Access,Room Service
Free Internet,Room Service
Free Internet,Room Service,Swimming Pool
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this...

```
unname(sapply(data, function(x) 
              paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\|"))), collapse=",")))

[1] "Free Internet,Internet Access,Room Service"          "Free Internet,Room Service"                         
[3] "Free Internet,Room Service,Swimming Pool"            "Free Internet,Restaurant,Room Service,Swimming Pool"
[5] "Room Service"
```

It splits each string by `|`, sorts the pieces, and pastes them back together with comma separators.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to split the values based on the pipe, sort the split vectors, and paste them back together. You can do

```
sapply(lapply(strsplit(data, "|", fixed=T), sort), paste, collapse="|")
```

Or wtih a little help from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
data %>% 
  strsplit("|", fixed=TRUE) %>% 
  map(sort) %>% 
  map_chr(paste, collapse="|")
```